# Library configuration in .net core?

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core

Started porting a few of our libraries over to .Net Core, and as we all know, the configuration handling changed greatly compared to Framework. Previously, we used [app.config.transforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/source-and-config-file-transformations) to inject the required settings (though I never liked that option tbh), which were then exposed through some static config class that handled type conversion and fallbacks etc (which I also don't really like). But as app.configs are going the way of the Dodo, that obviously won't be an option for the future any more, so I might as well put in some effort to have a nice solution.

So: What is the recommendation on handling configuration for libraries/nuget packages, especially in the context of .Net Core? Also in regard to (it seems to me) not knowing what kind of config the host application would use (ini, json, ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dotnet core there is a new configuration system, that supports xml, json, or ini. You can also read environment variables as part of this system. I'm not really sure libraries should use configuration. I'd think it would make more sense to take in options via constructor/method parameters.

That being said if you library takes in an `IConfigurationSection`, which can be passed by the caller. You library should be able to read settings that were configured by the application, for your library. You can even ask for a typed object with `IOptions<YourTyppedConfigurationSection>`

In dotnet core a common pattern seems to have a json file that is the base file, and then having a specific file for each environment.

So lets say you have an `appsettings.json`, you may also have an `appsettings.{environment}.json`, and if the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set it will use `appsettings.{environment}.json` as an override of the base file.

This is the typical set of code in the `Startup.cs` file which is the new `Global.asax`

```
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Msft has a great doc explaining, all about the configuration system here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

Comment: >  I'm not really sure libraries should use configuration.
Well, if the component needs to go to the DB, it needs some configuration input ;)

Anyhow, yeah, I'm thinking along the IOptions front as well, with some default config being defined in the module which can be overridden by consumers. Thanks for the inputs :)

Comment: I'm writing a library that has to call an API, the API url changes for each environment. Why should the consumer of the library have to know what my api url is?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the accepted answer when it talks about a Startup.cs file that a class library almost certainly wouldn't have. I think some hints are given here about injecting the config/section from the host using the class lib. It would be nice to have that fully explained in the context of a class lib and its host.